# -dpi option of Xephyr

Tags: x11, xorg, display, xephyr

What does the `-dpi` option of `Xephyr` do. I'm trying different values like this:

```
Xephyr -dpi 20 -screen 640x480 :1
```

and the programs running in the session don't look different in any way.

Answer (score 0):

`-dpi` sets the resolution (in [dots per inch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch), aka pixels per inch or 25.4 x pixels/mm).

You don't see any difference because most programs ignore the resolution reported by the X11 server (which is most of the time unreliable), or simply do everything in pixels.

You can easily check by running `xdpyinfo` on the `Xephyr` display:

```
$ Xephyr -dpi 20 :1 &
$ xdpyinfo -display :1 | grep resolution
  resolution:    20x20 dots per inch
$ Xephyr -dpi 177 :2 &
$ xdpyinfo -display :2 | grep resolution
  resolution:    177x177 dots per inch
```

BTW, if you want to get the *real* size of a monitor in an X11 app, you should get via [RandR](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/randrproto/randrproto.txt), but `xrandr` reports `0 x 0` on `Xephyr`:

```
$ xrandr -display :2 | grep connected
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
default connected 640x480+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
```